# Problem fetching data from firebase by using struct file

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
struct UserClass {
    var babyName: String!
    var babyHeight: String!
    var babyWeight: String!
    var babyURL: String!

    var uid: String!
    var reference:DatabaseReference!
    var key: String!

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
        guard let value = snapshot?.value as? [String:AnyObject],

            let uid = value["uid"] as? String,
            let babyName = value["BabyName"] as? String,
            let babyURL = value["BabyURL"] as? String,
            let babyHeight = value["BabyHeight"] as? String,
            let babyWeight = value["BabyWeight"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }

        self.key = snapshot?.key
        self.reference = snapshot?.ref
        self.uid = uid

        self.babyURL = babyURL
        self.babyName = babyName
        self.babyHeight = babyHeight
        self.babyWeight = babyWeight
    }

    func getuserData() -> String {
        return ("BabyName =  \(babyName)")
    }
}

func fetchCurrentUserInfo() {
        var currentUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child("\(userID)")
        handler = currentUserRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("User data = \(snapshot.value)")

            let user = UserClass(snapshot: snapshot)
            print(user?.babyName)
            self.babyName.text = user?.babyName
       })
   }
```

I am getting `user` data but not `user.babyName`. How can I fix this?

Comment: We would need to see your Firebase structure (as text please) and also how you are pulling in Firebase data to provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you, as the db structure is not mentioned in question. but you have to iterate children one by one and then use for loop to fetch the exact data from firebase.

```
reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
reference.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots
        {
            let userId = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "userID").value! as! String
            print(userId)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Careful as that is not always the case. If firebase observe is by .childAdded, .childChanged or .childRemoved, there's nothing to iterate over as a single node is presented in the snapshot. If it's by .value then the nodes may need to be iterated over but it's unclear from the question what the use case is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried with your code . but it shows error in userid = chlild.childsnapshot as child is unresolved identifier..

Comment: I might need your DB structure so that i may help you out in this.